# cannot get set-cookie header in Nativescript Http

Tags: angular, nativescript

I've tried to get http headers from an HttpInterceptor class.
When I tried to log the headers, set-cookie is not present.
However, when I tried to curl the url the set-cookie is present.

This is my HttpInterceptor class where I tried to access the headers:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { SessionService } from "../session/session.service";
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { tap } from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable()
export class HttpRequestInterceptor {
  constructor(private sessionService: SessionService) {

  }

  private isCachable(req: HttpRequest<any>): boolean {
    if (req.method != 'GET' && req.method != 'OPTIONS') {
      return false; 
    }

    return true;
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const successHandler = (response) => {
      // Intercept ecopayz successful form response.
      if (!this.isCachable(request) && response.headers && response.headers.get('x-redirect-url')) {
        window.location = response.headers.get('x-redirect-url');
      }

      var headers = response.headers;
      if (headers) {
        headers.headers.forEach((value, key) => {
          console.log(key, value);
        });
      }
    };

    const errorHandler = (error): any => {
      if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse ) {
        if (error.status === 401) {
          this.sessionService.clearSession();
        }
      }
    };

    request = request.clone({
      withCredentials: true
    });

    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      tap(successHandler, errorHandler),
    );
  }
}
```

PS: set-cookie header has HttpOnly flag.

Why is that so?

Thanks!

Comment: Cookies are handled differently on mobile platform, it's an [open feature request still with NativeScript's http client](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2424), for now you should able to read / write cookies using appropriate native apis.

Answer (score 0):

```
get(url: string, options: {
        headers?: HttpHeaders | {
            [header: string]: string | string[];
        };
        observe: 'response';
        params?: HttpParams | {
            [param: string]: string | string[];
        };
        reportProgress?: boolean;
        responseType: 'blob';
        withCredentials?: boolean;
    }): Observable<HttpResponse<Blob>>;
```

This is the http type definition file.

To begin with, you need to add 'observe: 'response' to the option.

It's a file download function, but just look at the code.

Exactly this option -> observe: 'response'

```
 public download(url: string) {
    return this.httpClient
      .get(url, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Accept': '*/*;',
          'Content-Type': 'application/octet-binary'
        }),
        responseType: 'blob',
        observe: 'response'
      });
  }
```

Comment: can I set this via Interceptor?

Comment: The Interceptor works when you send and respond to a GET request.
Use the option and check the interceptor for responses.